# how to drag image in a wxpython frame

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython, drawing, gdi

what is the easiest way to drag an image ( or text)  in a wx window ?
i need steps or a small example on how to do that.
thanx in advance

Comment: What do you mean, like "grab" on a bitmap and reposition it? If you're using StaticText you can Bind a EVT_MOUSE_DOWN/UP/MOTION to it, and use SetPosition to change where it's at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the PseudoDC example in the wxPython demo. The sample displays some random shapes within the window which you can grab and move around, you should be able to apply the concepts for an image.

You can download the **win32-docs-demos** from [here](http://wxpython.org/download.php#binaries)

Answer (score 0):

Install [wxpython demos](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython2.8-win32-docs-demos-2.8.10.1.exe), there is DragImage demostration in it.