# wx.Dragimage not working

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to make a virtual football playbook and need to be able to drag and drop a bitmap (in this case the X's or O's) for football plays. Here is some of my code.

```
class NewDefense(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'New Defense', wx.Point (0,0), size=(1000,700), style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('#2a2a2a')
        bg = wx.Panel(self)
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)

        x2 = wx.Image(defense, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        data = wx.BitmapDataObject(x2)

        ################# This is where the problem is.        

        drag = wx.DragImage(x2)
        drag.BeginDrag((0,0), self, fullScreen=False, rect=None)
        drag.Show() 
        #drag.Move()
        drag.EndDrag()
        #################  

        ##LINE
        wx.StaticBitmap(bg, wx.NewId(), x2, (330, 270), (x2.GetWidth(), x2.GetHeight()))
        wx.StaticBitmap(bg, wx.NewId(), x2, (410, 270), (x2.GetWidth(), x2.GetHeight()))
        wx.StaticBitmap(bg, wx.NewId(), x2, (490, 270), (x2.GetWidth(), x2.GetHeight()))
        wx.StaticBitmap(bg, wx.NewId(), x2, (570, 270), (x2.GetWidth(), x2.GetHeight()))

        ##LINE-BACKERS
        wx.StaticBitmap(bg, wx.NewId(), x2, (320, 160), (x2.GetWidth(), x2.GetHeight()))
        wx.StaticBitmap(bg, wx.NewId(), x2, (450, 160), (x2.GetWidth(), x2.GetHeight()))
        wx.StaticBitmap(bg, wx.NewId(), x2, (580, 160), (x2.GetWidth(), x2.GetHeight()))
```

will what I have now eventually work? what should I change or look into? I have searched this topic all over and it is quite confusing to me. any suggestions on what I could do?

NOTE: this is just a small piece of my code. If more is needed please let me know.

I try to run the program and I can't move the bitmap. And what should the pt be? The location of the bitmap or where it's moved to? If where it's moved to how do I set where it is to be moved to if I don't have an exact location yet because I want to be able to drag it

Comment: What exactly is your error? Telling us "not working" is like telling your doctor "I'm sick". We need more specific information.

Comment: Also, I did some googling and I found [this documentation](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.DragImage.html#Move) for the `Move()` method. Are you setting `pt`?

Comment: I try to run the program and I can't move the bitmap. And what should the pt be? The location of the bitmap or where it's moved to? If where it's moved to how do I set where it is to be moved to if I don't have an exact location yet because I want to be able to drag it

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! And for all the advice. As you can see I edited my question. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the advise of [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062864/how-to-drag-image-in-a-wxpython-frame), I downloaded and installed the wxPython demo kit (go to [this page](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) and download the demo that matches your wxPython version). It has some example code that you can take a look at (just open the demo and do a search for "dragimage").

The problem seems to be that you begin the dragging event right in your init (when you call `BeginDrag()`). According to the demo, `BeginDrag()` should only be called when you are actually starting the drag action, i.e. when the user clicks and holds on the image. Similarly, the `EndDrag()` method shouldn't be called until the user releases the image.

I'm not going to copy and paste the entire demo, but the main points are:

- You need to catch `wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN` events and check to see if the user clicked an image. If the user did click an image then you should call `BeginDrag()`
- You need to catch `wx.EVT_MOTION` events and check to see A) if you're currently dragging an image and B) if A then draw the image at the current mouse location.
- You need to catch `wx.EVT_LEFT_UP` events and, if the user is currently dragging an image, call the `EndDrag()` method and place the image in the final location.

If you download the wxPython demo, as I suggested above, you can see a full working example and all their code.